# Custom SkiaSharp CroppingCanvasView does not show up

Tags: maui, skiasharp

Following the things you told me in my last questions i was able to create an ImageCropper. I now wanted to change it from beeing a normal View xaml with code behind and ViewModel to a custom CanvasView so that i can Bind it better. Therefor i followed the look of the PhotoCropperCanvasView of this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/cropping
The Problem, however, my view is just white with nothing in it. I do not get Errors and i made sure the OnPaintSurface Method got called and the Bitmap was not empty. For Debuggign i tried simply drawing a rectangle but this did not show up either. I cannot find the flaw.

[image: Empty View, the Cropper does not appear]

The empty Page.

The CanvasView:

```cs
public class CroppingCanvasView : SKCanvasView, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // == Properties ==
    public SKBitmap Bitmap
    {
        get
        {
            return (SKBitmap)GetValue(BitmapProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BitmapProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public SKBitmap CroppedBitmap
    {
        get
        {
            SKBitmap destination = new SKBitmap(1080, 1080);
            SKRect destRect = SKRect.Create(0, 0, 1080, 1080);
            using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(destination))
            {
                canvas.Clear();
                canvas.DrawBitmap(CropBitmap, CroppingRect, destRect);
            }

            SKImage skImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(destination);
            SKData encoded = skImage.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 100);
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoded.AsStream().CopyTo(memory);
                CroppedImage = null;
                CroppedImage = memory.ToArray();
            }
            return (SKBitmap)GetValue(CroppedBitmapProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CroppedBitmapProperty, value);
        }
    }

    SKRect croppingRect;
    SKRect CroppingRect
    {
        get
        {
            return croppingRect;
        }
        set
        {
            SKRect rect = Matrix.Invert().MapRect(value);
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new CroppingRectChangedMessage(rect));
            croppingRect = rect;
        }
    }

    SKMatrix Matrix { get; set; }

    SKRect BitmapRect { get; set; }
    public SKBitmap CropBitmap { get; set; }
    public byte[] CroppedImage { get; set; }

    //SKSizeI CanvasSize { get; set; }

    // == Bindable Properties ==
    public static readonly BindableProperty BitmapProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Bitmap), typeof(SKBitmap), typeof(CroppingCanvasView));

    public static readonly BindableProperty CroppedBitmapProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CroppedBitmap), typeof(SKBitmap), typeof(CroppingCanvasView));

    // == fields ==
    TouchEffect touchEffect;
    Dictionary<long, SKPoint> touchDictionary;
    public CroppingCanvasView()
    {
        Matrix = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
        touchEffect = new TouchEffect();
        touchDictionary = new Dictionary<long, SKPoint>();
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = nameof(Bitmap))
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (Bitmap != null)
        {
            SKRect bitmapRect = new SKRect(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Width);
            CroppedBitmap = Bitmap;
            touchEffect.TouchAction += TouchEffect_TouchAction;
        }
    }

    // == override Methods ==
    protected override void OnPaintSurface(SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintSurface(e);

        SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear();
        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint() { Color = SKColor.FromHsl(100, 0, 0), StrokeWidth = 50 };

        // Display the bitmap
        Matrix = CalculateMatrix(Matrix);
        canvas.SetMatrix(Matrix);
        canvas.DrawRect(BitmapRect, paint);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, new SKPoint());
        //CanvasSize = info.Size;
        CroppingRect = SKRect.Create(0, 0, CanvasSize.Width, CanvasSize.Height);
    }

    protected override void OnParentSet()
    {
        base.OnParentSet();

        // Attach TouchEffect to parent view
        Parent.Effects.Add(touchEffect);
    }

    // == private Methods ==
    private void TouchEffect_TouchAction(object sender, Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking.TouchActionEventArgs e)
    {
        Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking.TouchTrackingPoint pt = e.Location;
        // Convert Xamarin.Forms point to pixels
        SKPoint point =
        new SKPoint((float)(CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / Width),
        (float)(CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / Height));

        switch (e.Type)
        {
            case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                // Find transformed bitmap rectangle
                SKRect rect = new SKRect(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
                rect = Matrix.MapRect(rect);

                // Determine if the touch was within that rectangle
                if (rect.Contains(point) && !touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    touchDictionary.Add(e.Id, point);
                }
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Moved:
                if (touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    // Single-finger drag
                    if (touchDictionary.Count == 1)
                    {
                        SKPoint prevPoint = touchDictionary[e.Id];

                        // Adjust the matrix for the new position
                        SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
                        matrix.TransX += point.X - prevPoint.X;
                        matrix.TransY += point.Y - prevPoint.Y;
                        matrix = CalculateMatrix(matrix);
                        Matrix = matrix;
                        InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    // Double-finger scale and drag
                    else if (touchDictionary.Count == 2)
                    {
                        // Copy two dictionary keys into array
                        long[] keys = new long[touchDictionary.Count];
                        touchDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

                        // Find index of non-moving (pivot) finger
                        int pivotIndex = (keys[0] == e.Id) ? 1 : 0;

                        // Get the three points involved in the transform
                        SKPoint pivotPoint = touchDictionary[keys[pivotIndex]];
                        SKPoint prevPoint = touchDictionary[e.Id];
                        SKPoint newPoint = point;

                        // Calculate two vectors
                        SKPoint oldVector = prevPoint - pivotPoint;
                        SKPoint newVector = newPoint - pivotPoint;
                        //SKPoint oldVector = prevPoint - new SKPoint(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width/2, (canvasView.CanvasSize.Width/2);

                        float scale = newVector.LengthSquared / oldVector.LengthSquared;

                        // Scaling factors are ratios of those
                        float scaleX = newVector.X / oldVector.X;
                        float scaleY = newVector.Y / oldVector.Y;

                        if (!float.IsNaN(scaleX) && !float.IsInfinity(scaleX) &&
                            !float.IsNaN(scaleY) && !float.IsInfinity(scaleY))
                        {
                            // If something bad hasn't happened, calculate a scale and translation matrix
                            SKMatrix scaleMatrix = SKMatrix.CreateScale(scale, scale, pivotPoint.X, pivotPoint.Y);
                            SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
                            matrix = matrix.PostConcat(scaleMatrix);
                            matrix = CalculateMatrix(matrix);
                            Matrix = matrix;
                            InvalidateSurface();
                        }
                    }

                    // Store the new point in the dictionary
                    touchDictionary[e.Id] = point;
                }

                break;

            case TouchActionType.Released:
            case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                if (touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    touchDictionary.Remove(e.Id);
                }
                break;
        }


    }

    private SKMatrix CalculateMatrix(SKMatrix getMatrix)
    {
        SKMatrix matrix = getMatrix;
        if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Size.Width < CanvasSize.Width ||
            matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Size.Height < CanvasSize.Height)
        {
            matrix.ScaleX = CanvasSize.Width / Bitmap.Width;
            matrix.ScaleY = CanvasSize.Height / Bitmap.Height;

        }
        if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Left > 0)
        {
            matrix.TransX -= matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Left;
        }
        if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Right < CanvasSize.Width)
        {
            matrix.TransX += -matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Right + CanvasSize.Width;
        }
        if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Top > 0)
        {
            matrix.TransY -= matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Top;
        }
        if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Bottom < CanvasSize.Height)
        {
            matrix.TransY += -matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Bottom + CanvasSize.Height;
        }
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

The View where i want to use it:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ImageCroppingTry5.ViewModels"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageCroppingTry5"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ImageCroppingTry5.Model"
             x:Class="ImageCroppingTry5.CutImagesView"
             x:DataType="viewModel:CutImagesViewModel"
             Title="CutImagesView">

    <Grid>
        <local:CroppingCanvasView Bitmap="{Binding UploadImages[0].Image}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public partial class CutImagesView : ContentPage
{
    public CutImagesView(ObservableCollection<UploadImageModel> files)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new CutImagesViewModel(files);
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public partial class CutImagesViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public ObservableCollection<UploadImageModel> uploadImages;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public SKBitmap map;

    public CutImagesViewModel(ObservableCollection<UploadImageModel> files)
    {
        UploadImages = new ObservableCollection<UploadImageModel>();
        UploadImages = files;
    }
}
```

Edit:  When i set the BackgroundColor i can see that the Canvas is on Screen but i do not know why the Bitmap does not get displayed. The Matrix is not empty as well as the Bitmap.

EDIT 2:
When i do not use the CalculateMatrix() Method and just set the Matrtix to Identity the Bitmap gets displayed. it seems like the matrix translates the Bitmap out of View but i do not understand why since in my old logic below everything worked fine and i made sure that the CanvasSize and the View Size are the Same in the new and old code.
Old working display logic:

```cs
SKBitmap Bitmap { get; set; }
Dictionary<long, SKPoint> touchDictionary = new Dictionary<long, SKPoint>();
SKMatrix matrix;
SKRect croppingRect;
SKRect CroppingRect
{
    get
    {
        return croppingRect;
    }
    set
    {
        SKRect rect = Matrix.Invert().MapRect(value);
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new CroppingRectChangedMessage(rect));
        croppingRect = rect;
    }
}

SKMatrix Matrix { get; set; }
SKSize CanvasSize { get; set; }
SKRect BitmapRect { get; set; }

public CroppingView(SKBitmap bitmap)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bitmap = bitmap;
    Matrix = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
    BitmapRect = new SKRect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    this.BindingContext = new CroppingViewModel(bitmap);
}

private async void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
    SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
    canvas.Clear();
    SKPaint paint = new SKPaint() { StrokeWidth = 0, };

    // Display the bitmap
    Matrix = CalculateMatrix(Matrix);
    canvas.SetMatrix(Matrix);
    canvas.DrawRect(BitmapRect, paint);
    canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, new SKPoint());
    CanvasSize = canvasView.CanvasSize;
    CroppingRect = SKRect.Create(0, 0, CanvasSize.Width, CanvasSize.Height);
}

private void TouchEffect_TouchAction(object sender, Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking.TouchActionEventArgs e)
{
    Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking.TouchTrackingPoint pt = e.Location;
    // Convert Xamarin.Forms point to pixels
    SKPoint point =
        new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                    (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));

    switch (e.Type)
    {
        case TouchActionType.Pressed:
            // Find transformed bitmap rectangle
            SKRect rect = new SKRect(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
            rect = Matrix.MapRect(rect);

            // Determine if the touch was within that rectangle
            if (rect.Contains(point) && !touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
            {
                touchDictionary.Add(e.Id, point);
            }
            break;

        case TouchActionType.Moved:
            if (touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
            {
                // Single-finger drag
                if (touchDictionary.Count == 1)
                {
                    SKPoint prevPoint = touchDictionary[e.Id];

                    // Adjust the matrix for the new position
                    SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
                    matrix.TransX += point.X - prevPoint.X;
                    matrix.TransY += point.Y - prevPoint.Y;
                    matrix = CalculateMatrix(matrix);
                    Matrix = matrix;
                    canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                }
                // Double-finger scale and drag
                else if (touchDictionary.Count == 2)
                {
                    // Copy two dictionary keys into array
                    long[] keys = new long[touchDictionary.Count];
                    touchDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

                    // Find index of non-moving (pivot) finger
                    int pivotIndex = (keys[0] == e.Id) ? 1 : 0;

                    // Get the three points involved in the transform
                    SKPoint pivotPoint = touchDictionary[keys[pivotIndex]];
                    SKPoint prevPoint = touchDictionary[e.Id];
                    SKPoint newPoint = point;

                    // Calculate two vectors
                    SKPoint oldVector = prevPoint - pivotPoint;
                    SKPoint newVector = newPoint - pivotPoint;
                    //SKPoint oldVector = prevPoint - new SKPoint(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width/2, (canvasView.CanvasSize.Width/2);

                    float scale = newVector.LengthSquared / oldVector.LengthSquared;

                    // Scaling factors are ratios of those
                    float scaleX = newVector.X / oldVector.X;
                    float scaleY = newVector.Y / oldVector.Y;

                    if (!float.IsNaN(scaleX) && !float.IsInfinity(scaleX) &&
                        !float.IsNaN(scaleY) && !float.IsInfinity(scaleY))
                    {
                        // If something bad hasn't happened, calculate a scale and translation matrix
                        SKMatrix scaleMatrix = SKMatrix.CreateScale(scale, scale, pivotPoint.X, pivotPoint.Y);
                        SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
                        matrix = matrix.PostConcat(scaleMatrix);
                        matrix = CalculateMatrix(matrix);
                        Matrix = matrix;
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                }

                // Store the new point in the dictionary
                touchDictionary[e.Id] = point;
            }

            break;

        case TouchActionType.Released:
        case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
            if (touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
            {
                touchDictionary.Remove(e.Id);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private SKMatrix CalculateMatrix(SKMatrix getMatrix)
{
    SKMatrix matrix = getMatrix;
    if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Size.Width < canvasView.CanvasSize.Width ||
        matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Size.Height < canvasView.CanvasSize.Height)
    {
        matrix.ScaleX = canvasView.CanvasSize.Width / Bitmap.Width;
        matrix.ScaleY = canvasView.CanvasSize.Height / Bitmap.Height;

    }
    if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Left > 0)
    {
        matrix.TransX -= matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Left;
    }
    if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Right < canvasView.CanvasSize.Width)
    {
        matrix.TransX += -matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Right + canvasView.CanvasSize.Width;
    }
    if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Top > 0)
    {
        matrix.TransY -= matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Top;
    }
    if (matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Bottom < canvasView.CanvasSize.Height)
    {
        matrix.TransY += -matrix.MapRect(BitmapRect).Bottom + canvasView.CanvasSize.Height;
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `UploadImageModel` and `CroppingRectChangedMessage`? If it is convenient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github and post the link here so that we can test on our side?